# How to visualize the frequency of a satellite?

Tags: frequency, wavelength, satellites

For a satellite I know the period `T` and frequency `f = 1/T`. For instance, for an earth skimming satellite with period `T = 5100` seconds, the frequency is `f = 0.00019` 1/sec. What does the number `0.00019` represent? Is it the angle in radian per second?

And how do I visualize the wavelength of the satellite's orbit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the satellite has a period of $T$ seconds (so it makes one complete revolution in this time), then its frequency of revolution $\frac{1}{T}\ s^{-1}$ represents the number of revolutions it makes per second (assuming circular orbit). So if $T=5100\ s$ then the satellite makes $0.00019$ revolutions per second, or $f=0.00019\ s^{-1}$.

If you wanted to determine the angular frequency, or the frequency in radians per second, then you would calculate $$\omega=\frac{2\pi}{T}=2\pi f\approx 0.0012\ \text{radians}\ s^{-1}$$

You might think that since an object has a frequency, then it should have a wavelength. But here, frequency or angular frequency are terms associated with the speed or velocity of the object. E.g., angular frequency being the magnitude of its angular velocity, which is a (pseudo) *vector*. In this particular case, physically the object does not possess a wavelength. Wavelengths are associated with waves, so in the context of your question, we don't really attribute a wavelength to such a situation.

Comment: Just for completeness, note that your explanation of frequency only applies to circular orbits. For elliptical orbits, the fraction of a complete revolution per second is not a constant.  The constant would be the area swept by a radial from the planet to the satellite.

Comment: That’s correct. Edited. Thanks

Comment: Things were clearer in the olden days when I was a kid, before the unit s${}^{-1}$ became Hz.   The unit of frequency was 'cps',  cycles per second.